# Issue deactivating a solution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, template, solution

Not sure why this is happening but when i try to deactivate a template in the solution gallery i get the following exception:

> Unable to access web scoped feature (Id:
>   7b1b586a-8460-44fb-a276-fc82be9a1d94) because it references a
>   non-existent or broken web (Id: 584fc404-ec10-4e82-ab6d-486d78532e52)
>   on site 'https://sp.harlow-hrk.com/sites/vendors'.  Exception:
>   System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected
>   range.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.get_Item(Guid id)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureEnumeratorBase.GetCachedWeb(SPSite
>   site, Guid webId, Guid featureId)

This is on a sharepoint enterprise server.  Looking for recommendations so that i can deactivate and remove this solution from the gallery.  TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to go the the recycle bin of the site collection and make sure that everything from 'End User Recycle Bin Items' ***AND*** 'Deleted from End User Recycle Bin Items' are deleted.  I made the mistake of not deleting from the Deleted From view and that is why it still wouldn't deactivate.  Hurray!  Posting so it is here also

Comment: You beat me to it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Does the web in question exist in your Site Collection Recycle Bin? If so, empty the recycle bin and try deleting it then.